# Using an interface from class in C#

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I have a class that has an interface in it like so:

```
 public class hcmTerminal {

    ... Code

    public interface onDataReceived {
        void isCompleted(bool done);
    }

}
```

inside this class I I have the public property:

```
public onDataReceived mDataReceived;
```

then I have a function to set the delegate:

```
public void setDataReceived(onDataReceived dataReceived) { mDataReceived = dataReceived; }
```

Inside the hcmTerminal class I am am calling the delegate :

```
mDataReceived.isCompleted(true);
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to actually get when that delegate gets called, In java I can go:

```
myTerminal.setDataReceived(new hcmTerminal.onDataReceived(){

    @Override
    public void isCompleted(boolean done){

        ... Code

    }

});
```

But if I try that in C# I get:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract or interface
>   'hcmTerminal.onDataReceived'

I haven't had to create a interface in C# before. this code is coming from how  I implemented it in Java.

Comment: I would *very* strongly urge you to follow the naming conventions of .NET when writing C#, and Java when writing Java. Currently you're violating both.

Comment: Just so you know a method of an interface is not a delegate.  C# has a delegate type it uses instead of interfaces.  But if you use an interface you have to create a class that implements that interface.

Comment: As for your interface - is there any reason you're creating an interface rather than a delegate? You *talk* about a delegate, but you're declaring an interface...

Comment: Shouldn't you just use events instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I've found the best duplicate, more - https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20equivalent%20of%20java%20anonymous%20interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using events you can accomplish that by

```
 class HcmTerminal {
      public event Action<bool> OnDataReceived;

      public void Launch()
      {
           OnDataReceived?.Invoke(true /*or false*/);
      }

 }
```

You can then do:

```
var myTerminal = new HcmTerminal();
myTerminal.OnDataReceived += (isCompleted) => {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a class implementing the interface:

```
class MyDataReceived : hcmTerminal.onDataReceived {
    public void isCompleted(bool done) {
        Console.WriteLine("call to isCompleted. done={0}", done);
    }
}
```

Now you can call `myTerminal.setDataReceived(new MyDataReceived())`

However, this is a Java solution coded in C#, not a "native" C# solution. A better approach is to define a delegate in place of an interface:

```
public class HcmTerminal {
    ... Code
    public delegate void OnDataReceived(bool done);
}
```

This would let you use multiple C# features for supplying delegate implementation, such as providing a method name, supplying an anonymous delegate, or using a lambda:

```
myTerminal.setDataReceived((done) => {
    Console.WriteLine("call to isCompleted. done={0}", done);
});
```